# How do I create a torch diagonal matrices with different element in each batch?

Tags: pytorch, torch, tensor

I want to create a tensor like

```
 tensor([[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],[[2,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,2]]]])
```

That is, when a torch tensor B of size (1,n) is given, I want to create a torch tensor A of size (n,3,3) such that A[i] is an B[i] * (identity matrix of size 3x3).

Without using 'for sentence', how do I create this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [torch.einsum](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum) (Einstein's notation of sum and product)

```
A = torch.eye(3)
b = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
torch.einsum('ij,k->kij', A, b)
```

Will return:

```
tensor([[[1., 0., 0.],
     [0., 1., 0.],
     [0., 0., 1.]],

    [[2., 0., 0.],
     [0., 2., 0.],
     [0., 0., 2.]],

    [[3., 0., 0.],
     [0., 3., 0.],
     [0., 0., 3.]]])
```